# Where is dbeaver.ini located if DBeaver is installed via windows store?

Tags: dbeaver

Where is dbeaver.ini located if DBeaver is installed via windows store as an app?

Background of my question: I want to use a different VM

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it under:

`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\DBeaverCorp.DBeaverCE_***`

(which does not really help me as I realized it is almost impossible to do changes there)

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.